# Guardar resultado bucle for en una columna en Python

Tags: python, bucle-for, bucles

No entiendo que estoy haciendo mal. He hecho en otras ocasiones algo semejante a lo que intento ahora y no me daba ningún error. Alguna tontería se me escapará, no sé...

Necesito enumerar unas filas para crear un ID para luego poder trabajar teniendo siempre la misma referencia de cada fila. Un ID, vaya.

Hago un bucle For que pase por el df (df_test) y a cada fila sume 1 a n. Luego quiero que el resultado de ese bucle se guarde en una nueva columna de df_Test

```
n=1
for identificador_usuario in (df_test):
    n=n+1
df_test["identificador_usuario"].index=df_test.apply(identificador_usuario,axis=1)
```

¿Qué hago mal?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias

Comment: quieres agregar un id identificador como indice, para cada fila?

Comment: Sí, pero que se mantenga siempre igual, que no cambie, aunque filtre o desmonte por completo el df...

Comment: y valores de tu index serían de 1 hasta n?

Comment: Al parecer el error esta en lo que le pasas al `apply`, no es un objeto `callable` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49140164/tensorflow-error-unsupported-callable

Comment: @LucasDamian Si. Hay varios documentos y cada uno tiene un número de filas distinto, así que estaría bien que fuese hasta n.

Comment: puedes intentar hacer algo como esto ? `df_test['indices'] = [i+1 for i in range(len(df_test))]` asi das de alta la columna `indices` y luego  `new_df = df.set_index('indices')` y para acceder por ejemplo al 1 `new_df.loc[1]` De esta manera debería funcionar

Comment: @LucasDamian Esto ha funcionado! Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente utiliza un range:

```
     rows=df_test.shape[0]+1
     df_test["identificador_usuario"]=[n for n in range(1,rows)]
```

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo para qué llevas la cuenta en n si luego no la utilizas....
de todas formas, tal como está el código, la línea

```
df_test["identificador_usuario"].index=df_test.apply(identificador_usuario,axis=1)
```

está fuera del for, tienes que indentarla para que quede dentro, es normal que te de error ya que identificador_usuario no existe fuera del for.

Comment: Ya lo he intentado intendándola, pero sigue dando error. La cuenta de "n" la llevo porque me sirve para enumerar cada fila, que al final es lo que quiero agregar como una nueva columna... ¿Qué puedo hacer? Solo quiero enumerar cada fila en una nueva columna

Comment: @Marc, a no ser que tengas más líneas de código dentro del _for_ que no has incluido, el valor de n se va a pisar en cada iteración y al final solo tendrás guardado en n la cantidad de elementos que tiene el array

Comment: Actualizo la pregunta para que veas con una imagen que no hay nada...

Comment: entiendo que df_test es un dataframe de pandas que ya existe en memoria no?

Comment: Sí... df_test. Lo he vuelto a cargar todo y nada. Me da el mismo problema.